# Anyone try generating C# classes from http://schemas.opengis.net?

Tags: c#, gml, ogc, proxy

I'd like to generate gml/wfs/wms classes from the OGC schemas.  Using xsd2code I receive numerous errors, one of them being "Invalid particle derivation by restriction".  I'm curious is anyone has successfully generated .NET classes from the OGC schemas and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it and seems to be working although i didn't know such a thing existed :-)
Here is what i did.

1. Downloaded the gml schema from here..[gml schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/gml-3_3_0.zip)
2. Extracted the zip
3. In Visual Studio 2008, Created a blank project in c#.
4. dragged the extracted files to this project using windows explorer.
5. Right clicked a xsd file and clicked Run Xsd2Code..
   [image]
6. Got the results after a 1 minute wait..
   [image]

Comment: It's true that it does generate some classes this way but it does not, in general, work.  For example I attempted this same thing on 3.2.1/gml.xsd and received "The global element 'http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2:AbstractObject has already been declared."  It seems the xsd is incorrect or otherwise incompatible with .NET.  It appears to be defined in 3.2.1\gmlBase.xsd as well as several xsd's under iso\19139.

Comment: @user2023 - which is the visual Studio version you are using?

Comment: 2010 Professional 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel...don't think it's VS that is the problem because I get the same error when running Xsd2Code from the command line.  Are you able to generate the proxies starting with 3.2.1/gms.xsd?  I got my xsd's from [here](http://schemas.opengis.net/SCHEMAS_OPENGIS_NET.zip).

Comment: @user2023 - oops..i am getting the same error with that file..